# How do I check Windows Phone useragent with javascript?

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I can check for iPhone with this code:

```
(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))
```

But I want to target Windows Phone with this userAgent:

```
Mozilla/4.0(compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; 
Motorola_ES405B_19103; Windows Phone 6.5.3.5)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using a `match` matching what you want to use? If you have and it doesn't work, please say what you have tried.

Comment: Yea I have tried. But I want to match a certain version of Windows phone.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`Windows Phone` certainly seems to be the term you want to match. So just exchange `iPhone` in your matcher with that term and you're good to go!

---

As mentioned in the comments: looking also for `iemobile` will give you an even broader range of detected microsoft mobiles OSes.

e.g.:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)){
    alert('Is a windows phone!');
}

if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iemobile/i)){
    alert('Is some mobile IE browser!')
}

// and probably less common, but still useful:
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/WPDesktop/i)){
    alert('It is a windows phone in desktop mode!')
}
```

Comment: Does that go all the way up to 7.5 or can i specify min version aswell? Like if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone < 7) or something like that..

Comment: It matches using a regular expression, so can only match what you see. But since there is the version number included in the user agent, you still can use `(navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone [1-6]/i))` to match all versions from one to six.

Comment: if you look for iemobile it would also try to make it compatible with windows mobile and ce versions.

Comment: thank you for the comment, i've updated my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: whindows phone User agent: --> (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop) <--

Comment: Should add /WPDesktop/i to work on WPhone 8 desktop mode

Answer (score 19):

Nokia Lumia or any WPhone browser has desktop and mobile browsing mode, IEMobile sends different user agent. Desktop mode does not send Windows Phone X.Y model argument. Find Windows+ARM+Touch+WPDesktop tags and possibly screen size to guess wphone or tablet. Its a hack I know.

**Lumia 920 WPhone 8, desktop mode**
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)

**Lumia 920 WPhone 8**
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920)

**Lumia 820 WPhone 8**
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 820)

**Lumia 630 WPhone 8**
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 8.1; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; NOKIA; id313-3) like Gecko

**Lumia 630 WPhone 8, desktop mode**
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; WPDesktop; NOKIA; id313-3) like Gecko

**Lumia 800 WPhone 7.5**
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; NOKIA; Lumia 800)

**Lumia 900**
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; NOKIA; Lumia 900)

**WP7.5 IEMobile9 desktop mode**
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; XBLWP7; ZuneWP7)

Answer (score 2):

**[Working Fiddle for Windows Phone IE](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/eqq3j/3/)**

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iemobile/i)) 
{                                       
    alert('IE is Issue Explorer');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function isIEMobile() {
    var regExp = new RegExp("IEMobile", "i");
    return navigator.userAgent.match(regExp);
}
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to add a little body to you answer to explain your code. And perhaps add a reference or two.