# Binding events conditionally in Backbone - mobile or desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

To make it easier to read i put everything under the `initialize` function.
Is there something wrong here? The alert gets triggered so it's not the condition.
I have the share actions hidden and would like to show them on Hover on desktop and Tap on mobile given the hover impossibility.
Am I missing something here?
`console.log()` doesn't throw any errors.

```
App.Views.Title = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize:function(){

    _.bindAll(this,"stickToTop");
    this.template = _.template($("#title").html());
    this.render();
    $(window).scroll(this.stickToTop);

    var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);
    var share = this.$(".share");

    if(isMobile){

        // alert('mobile')
        share.on('click' , this.shareMobile , this);

    }else{
        // alert('not mobile')
        share.on('hover' , this.shareDesktop , this);

    }

},
...
```

Comment: and I guess `windows phone` is missing from you user agent regex http://stackoverflow.com/a/9926619/429521

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you're binding the events the jquery-way not the Backbone way, by using [delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents).

I suggest you to try the following:

```
if(isMobile){

    // alert('mobile')
    this.delegateEvents({"click .share" : "shareMobile"});

}else{
    // alert('not mobile')
    this.delegateEvents({"hover .share" : "shareDesktop"});

}
```

Hope this helps.

------- UPDATE -------

I tested this out myself, you can do this in a very beautiful way!

First remove all that isMobile and delegate events crap from your initialize method, it just clutters it up! Then make the Backbone.View events hash as a function that returns an events hash (Yes, you CAN do that!)

```
events: function() {
  // check for the mobility HERE!
  var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);
  var events_hash = {
    // insert all the events that go here regardless of mobile or not
  };
  if (isMobile) {
    _.extend(events_hash, {"click .share": "shareMobile"});
  } else {
    _.extend(events_hash, {"hover .share": "shareDesktop"});
  }
  return events_hash;
}
```

Et voilà!

Comment: Great! It work perfectly... I didn't see it in the documentation.

Comment: sweet. Just learned something new. I have had items in the events property not work correctly if the view was not declared after doc.ready. this.delegateEvents is a much more idomatic to backbone then how I have been getting around it

Comment: check out the update if you want to learn more, learned something myself as well!

Comment: Awesome! I wish i could give you another +1. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant update, returning the events hash.  I've been trying to work that out for a while

Answer (score 1):

I will do it in this way:

```
App.Views.Title = Backbone.View.extend({

    events : {
      'hover .mobile .share' : 'shareMobile',
      'click .desktop .share' : 'shareDesktop'
    },

    initialize:function(){

        //stuff...

        var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);

        if(isMobile){
           this.$el.addClass('mobile');
        }else{
           this.$el.addClass('desktop');
        }

    }
    //stuff
});
```

Comment: I feel it more readable, and homogeneous with the Backbone declaration of events.

Comment: However i prefer @jakee's approach 'cause all the logic happens within the event function and returns the object without cluttering the initialize function nor adding additional classes, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Umm.. is it that you define $share but then use share.on (no $)?

Comment: oohh! Nono, it's not that, copy/paste error, it's been updated! Thanks!