# How do I redirect windows phones (but not desktop windows) to a mobile site using html?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, windows-phone-8

I've had mobile device redirection for quite a while now, but something that's bugged me is that (to the best of my knowledge) Windows Phone users aren't being redirected.

My question is, How do I redirect Windows Phone users?

#### My Code:

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )
{ window.location = "http://m.ctworkshop.us/"; }
</script>
```

Is it possible? What name would I add to do so, if it is?

Ps. adding "Windows" to that list redirects desktop Windows which I don't want to do.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not make the site responsive?

Comment: Possible duplicate?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926504/how-do-i-check-windows-phone-useragent-with-javascript

Comment: look for the string "Windows Phone" not just windows. here's a useragent string for windows phone: `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
```

Here's a [blog post from a Microsoft employee](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eternalcoding/2014/12/16/correctly-detecting-windows-phone-when-sniffing-user-agent-string/) about correctly detecting Windows phones which uses the same strategy.

Comment: Sorry I never came back to this, totally forgot I asked the question.
I think that'll work perfectly, and it was a simple fix of course....Thank you so much!