# Match a particular string in navigator.userAgent and get the details from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a compare function.

**Objective:**

To first get the information by using `navigator.userAgent`. Then, I'll  find a particular string (which is the phone's model code) from an array of objects which contains the phone's model code in it. Detailed explanation below.

I tried the help of the following, but it doesn't completely work for me:

[Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

[How do I check Windows Phone useragent with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926504/how-do-i-check-windows-phone-useragent-with-javascript/19156408)

**What I tried:**

```
    <div id="compare-phone-display"></div>
    
    <script>
    function compare(){

        var detectPhone = navigator.userAgent;
        var phoneModels = [
            {
                code: "SM-N975F",
                name: "Note 10"
            },
            {
                code: "SM-G900P",
                name: "Galaxy S5"
            }
        ]

        for(i = 0; i < phoneModels.length; i++) {
            if(detectPhone.match(phoneModels[i].code/g)) {
                document.getElementById("compare-phone-display").innerHTML = phoneModels[i].name;
            }
        }

    }
compare();
</script>
```

**Explanation of what I was trying to do:**

First, I create an array of objects. The most important part here would be the `code: value`.

What I am trying to do is, from the output of `navigator.userAgent`, I want to find a part of the string that matches the `code: value` of the array.

So, for example, if the navigator.userAgent outputs something like:

"xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxSM-N975f"

then, I want to be able to detect that SM-N975f and be able to output its name property set in the array.

eg; "xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxSM-N975f" should be able to display "Note 10" in `#compare-phone-display`

Can someone point me in the right direction with this as its not displaying the name of the phone? Am I having a syntax error or is my entire logic is wrong?

Comment: Why try for a regular expression match in the first place here; none of your codes appear to contain any wildcards, repetition etc. A simple _string match_ (indexOf) would suffice here, if you don't need to match any dynamic patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The error comes from the way that you are constructing the Regular Expression,**

You cannot place the text directly in the expression, you have to instead use the [`RegExp Constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp) like this:

```js
new RegExp(phoneModels[i].code, 'g')
```

**Demo:**

```js
function compare(userAgent = navigator.userAgent) {
  var detectPhone = userAgent;
  var phoneModels = [
    {
      code: 'SM-N975F',
      name: 'Note 10',
    },
    {
      code: 'SM-G900P',
      name: 'Galaxy S5',
    },
  ];

  for (i = 0; i < phoneModels.length; i++) {
    if (detectPhone.match(new RegExp(phoneModels[i].code, 'g'))) {
      //document.getElementById('compare-phone-display').innerHTML = phoneModels[i].name;
      return phoneModels[i].name;
    }
  }
}

let S5 = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Mobile Safari/537.36'; // Galaxy S5
let NOTE10 = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-N975F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Mobile Safari/537.36'; // Note 10

console.log(compare(S5));
console.log(compare(NOTE10));
```

```html
I made some changes so that the code works as a demo.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything in your function.

Try something like this and see what is the output:

```
function compare(){

        var detectPhone = navigator.userAgent;
        var phoneModels = [
            {
                code: "SM-N975F",
                name: "Note 10"
            },
            {
                code: "SM-G900P",
                name: "Galaxy S5"
            }
        ]
        let model = document.getElementById("compare-phone-display")
        for(i = 0; i < phoneModels.length; i++) {
            if(detectPhone.match(phoneModels[i].code/g)) {
                model.innerHTML = phoneModels[i].name;
            }
        }
        return model.innerHTML;
    }
```